# A way to listen window mode changes WndProc

Tags: c++, windows, window, directx-11, wndproc

I'd like to refresh my swap chain when my game switches from windowed to fullscreen and vice versa, for the moment I only found uMsg == WM_SIZE which but it's not optimal, fullscreen to borderless doesn't work unfortunately.... Is there another message ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For "fullscreen" vs. "windowed" handling using DXGI, there are two basic approaches:

1. Let DXGI do it for you via `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH`.
2. Use the flag `DXGI_MWA_NO_WINDOW_CHANGES` and handle it yourself. You in fact do use `WM_SIZE` to determine the changes. You may also want to use `DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER` and handle the ALT+ENTER shortcut in your WndProc.

See [Microsoft Docs: DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI) Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/dxgi-best-practices).

For windowed mode, a challenge with `WM_SIZE` is that as the 'rubberband' rectangle is adjusted you get a lot of these messages, and resizing the backbuffer is not that fast. One solution here is to use `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` and `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` so you can pause the resizing until it's completed.

See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d11game_win32_dr/Main.cpp) a detailed WndProc implementation.

> One final point: There are actually several definitions for 'fullscreen'. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/).